# PHP , функция next(), правильно перенести массив на один элемент вперёд

Tags: php, key

У меня есть данный код

```
foreach ($usersWithRole as $key => $users) {
        $usersArray[] = [
            $key => $users->userid
        ];
    }

    $oneDimensionalArrayWithUsers = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $usersArray);
    if (in_array($lastUserAssignedId, $oneDimensionalArrayWithUsers)) {
        $keyArrayFromValue = array_search($lastUserAssignedId,$oneDimensionalArrayWithUsers);
    } else {
        $staffMemberId = $oneDimensionalArrayWithUsers[0];
    }
```

Я хочу перенести один элементе массива `$oneDimensionalArrayWithUsers` вперёд от ключа, который храниться в переменной `$keyArrayFromValue`. 
Если дойдет до конца массива - перескакивало на его начало(то есть на 1-вый элемент массива)

в функции next() ничего об этом не говориться, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: $oneDimensionalArrayWithUsers[$key+1]

Comment: Окей.Но что делать, если дойдет к концу массива? Я хочу чтобы оно вернуло мне на начало.

Comment: А конца массива у вас и не будет))) это же PHP

Comment: перенести "вперёд" на место другого элемента? старые данные в этом ключе просто теряются или их тоже надо куда-то переносить

Comment: пример входного и выходного массива приведите с различными ситуациями.

Comment: что именно делает данный код и какая задача глобально? то есть что нужно сделать по сути, а не технически поменять ключи? что хранится в $usersWithRole? почему в цикле переменная $users а не $user?  Если отвлечься от юзеров и ролей, то из какого массива на входе что нужно получить на выходе?